# llvm ir back to human-readable source language?

Tags: c++, programming-languages, llvm, clang

Is there an easy way of going from llvm ir to working source code?

Specifically, I'd like to start with some simple C++ code that merely modifies PODs (mainly arrays of ints, floats, etc), convert it to llvm ir, perform some simple analysis and translation on it and then convert it back into C++ code?

It don't really mind about any of the names getting mangled, I'd just like to be able to hack about with the source before doing the machine-dependent optimisations.

Comment: LLVM assembly is relatively readable, provided you're familiar with low level details. You can instruct `llc` to output C code (`-march=c`) - however, the result won't be pretty.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is an issue here... it might not be possible to easily represent the IR back into the language.

I mean, you'll probably be able to get *some* representation, but it might be *less* readable.

The issue is that the IR is not concerned with high-level semantic, and without it...

I'd rather advise you to learn to read the IR. I can read a bit of it without that much effort, and I am far from being a llvm expert.

Otherwise, you can C code from the IR. It won't be much more similar to your C++ code, but you'll perhaps feel better without ssa and phi nodes.

Comment: what is a phi node? phi = ?

Comment: @paulm: It is [intrinsic to SSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single_assignment_form).

Answer (score 37):

There are number of options actually. The 2 that you'll probably be interested in are `-march=c` and `-march=cpp`, which are options to llc.

Run:

```
llc -march=c -o code.c code.ll
```

This will convert the LLVM bitcode in `code.ll` back to C and put it in `code.c`.

Also:

```
llc -march=cpp -o code.cpp code.ll
```

This is different than the C output engine. It actually will write out C++ code that can be run to reconstruct the IR. I use this personal to embed LLVM IR in a program without having to deal with parsing bitcode files or anything.

`-march=cpp` has more options you can see with `llc --help`, such as `-cppgen=` which controls how much of the IR the output C++ reconstructs.

Comment: With my own (recent - i.e. 4.0) builds of LLVM, `llc --version` lists about 30 targets, but C and C++ are not included. I tried using Ubuntu's apt-get to install the older LLVM (3.8), and see that it does include the C++ backend, but not the C backend. The "Building LLVM with CMake" page (llvm.org/docs/CMake.html) indicates that all targets are built by default. Have the C and C++ targets recently been removed?

Comment: Same here, 4.0 SVN build is missing the c and cpp backends

Comment: @aerkenemesis: Official support for the C and C++ backends were removed as they were lagging behind and there was not enough interest in maintaining them, so this option is no longer possible: see http://releases.llvm.org/3.1/docs/ReleaseNotes.html#changes . In the mean time, the Julia team maintains their own unofficial C backend at https://github.com/JuliaComputing/llvm-cbe .

Answer (score 25):

CppBackend was removed. We have no -march=cpp and -march=c option since 2016-05-05, r268631.

Comment: Any more info, such as reasons why or the actual notice of deprecation?

Comment: http://releases.llvm.org/3.1/docs/ReleaseNotes.html#changes

"The C backend has been removed. It had numerous problems, to the point of not being able to compile any nontrivial program."

Comment: Looks like not over with it yet: https://github.com/JuliaComputing/llvm-cbe