# Converting LLVM-IR into a C like language

Tags: c, llvm, llvm-ir

I am working on a project where I have to a write code for converting LLVM-IR into a C-like language. This language has constructs very similar to C. After doing a little survey, I found that upto version 3.0 of LLVM there existed a file named CBackend.cpp responsible for conversion of LLVM-IR into C code. What I want to check is run this CBackend.cpp file on my input file of LLVM-IR and generate C code.

The command for this is: llc -march=c -o code.c code.ll

where the code.ll file is the input file containing the input llvm-ir and code.c is the output file containing the resultant C code.

What I am facing is, I have LLVM version 3.4svn installed on my ubuntu system and there is no CBackend.cpp file in this version as the file has been upgraded to CppBackend.cpp (which converts LLVM-IR to C++). Which command can I use to run this CBackend.cpp file on my LLVM-IR input file to get the corresponding C code in version 3.4svn of LLVM ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This thread indicates it may have been broken - http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/llvmdev/2012-April/049124.html . If you still want it, why not download an older version from here - http://llvm.org/releases/download.html ?

Comment: @Leeor: Actually I din't upgrade my llvm. I have version 3.4svn installed from the beginning and it does not have the CBackend file. They seem to remove it from the versions which came after 3.0 . So, I want the command to run this file on my version.

Comment: @Leeor: I have that CBackend.cpp file with me. I just want the command to run this file on my version. As installing a lower version is just not the right solution for me now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The C backend was dropped in release 3.1 because it was not maintained and started developing code rot, becoming a burden. Since no maintainer stepped up, it was removed from the tree. From the [release notes of 3.1](http://llvm.org/releases/3.1/docs/ReleaseNotes.html):

> The C backend has been removed. It had numerous problems, to the point
>   of not being able to compile any nontrivial program.

In August 2012 a [thread on llvmdev](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/llvmdev/2012-August/052858.html) discussed reviving the C backend, but I don't think it ended up anywhere useful.

You can still download LLVM version 3.0 (from the [releases page](http://llvm.org/releases/index.html)), build it and see the C backend in action, study its code, etc. For your specific purpose - looking at the code and figuring out how it works, the 3.0 C backend should be good enough.

Comment: and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180914/llvm-ir-back-to-human-readable-source-language