LLVM API for generating C++ source code from some declarative description
Does LLVM have an API for generating C++ source code from some declarative description? By the latter I mean something similar to the DSL used in the matcher library; or an AST, if you can build it manually and then "force" LLVM to generate С++ code from it.

I don't believe LLVM does that.  It probably could do that, but someone would have to implement that for LLVM.

You may find llvm ir to C++ of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5188406/4641116

Thanks, @Eljay! I'll take a look!

You may want to consider some sort of text templating library.  I think something of the kind exists in the open source compiler ecosystem, as I vaguely recall gfortran using it (maybe to build intrinsics).  A little poking suggests that what gfortran uses (or used) may be m4.

@Eljay, llc does not have a backend for C++ anymore... P.S. I'm interested in relatively recent versions of LLVM (18/19).

I searched a bit, and I found a few projects for generating C++ code (not using LLVM though).  Some are for a limited use case, some appear to be abandoned efforts.  Haxe, HipHop, Qt Meta-Object Compiler (moc), ShedSkin, Oracle PRO*C/C++ for embedded SQL, Coffee++, (Sean Baxter's) Circle, (Sean Baxter's) New Circle, (Sean Baxter & C++ Alliance's) Safe-C++, (Herb Sutter's) C++ syntax 2 (CppFront), SugarCpp, Cereberus X, Dafny, and Nim.  Also an honorable mention for Emscripten which takes LLVM bytecode and generates JavaScript.
